# Does Github copilot analyze my whole code?

Tags: github-copilot

I would like to know if the current version of Github Copilot analyzes my entire code, my entire code base, or just the active file and a few open files?
I use the jetbrains suite (I don't know if that matters).

If not, do you know if Copilot will use my whole code to make suggestions?
I haven't found any clear answers on the web.

Answer (score 2):

> GitHub Copilot analyzes the context in the file you are editing,

Actually, since Q1 2024, you can specify the file you need Copilot to work on:

> ### [Code faster and better with GitHub Copilot’s new features in Visual Studio](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-01-30-code-faster-and-better-with-github-copilots-new-features-in-visual-studio) (Jan. 2024)
>
> We have introduced two new powerful features to the latest Visual Studio Copilot Chat extension: slash commands (/) that allow you to direct Copilot to perform specific tasks, and context Variables (#) that allow you to specify a file for Copilot to focus its answer on.
> These features are available on the latest [Chat extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSGitHubCopilot) that is compatible with [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8 and higher](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
>
> The context variables feature enables you to add files from your solution into your questions using the `#` symbol.
> By referencing a file in this way, you allow Copilot to access the content of the file and provide more targeted answers about it.
> For example, you can ask “How does the `#file:'Main.cs'` file work?” or “What is the purpose of the `#file:'Calculator.cs'` file?” and get relevant answers from Copilot Chat.
> You can add multiple files to one question.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/image1_bcdd08.jpg?w=934&resize=934%2C1024]
>
> Besides these main features, you can also explore our other exciting new [preview features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/copilot-chat-slash-commands-and-context-variables/)
>
> Join the discussion within [GitHub Community](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/copilot).

Comment: Me:
what is the purpose of the #file:index.js ?

GitHub Copilot:
I'm sorry for any confusion, but as an AI, I don't have the ability to directly access or view your files. If you could provide the content or a snippet of the index.js file, I would be able to help explain its purpose or functionality.

Comment: @SimonNazarenko Strange: I just tried it, typing # made me select file, which in turn opened a drop list where I selected the file, and Copilot did explain the purpose of that file. The point is, I did not type `#file:aFile`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following article from GitHub about Copilot:

> GitHub Copilot analyzes the context in the file you are editing, as
> well as related files [...]

Source:
https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/overview-of-github-copilot/about-github-copilot-individual

Comment: The problem is, I found this article that says "We want to let GitHub Copilot see your entire repo when it comes up with its suggestions." 
https://githubnext.com/projects/copilot-view/
Then... Is for all the source code or only open files?

Comment: Sharing this answer I found that summarizes what is written in this article (https://github.blog/2023-05-17-how-github-copilot-is-getting-better-at-understanding-your-code/): https://community.openai.com/t/codepilot-github-copilot-on-steroids/395945/5

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be an external library and not included in copilot :'(

Comment: Nevertheless the comment on this external lib summarizes, that GH Copilot never has all of your code but creates a vector db and snippets from that are used in context for creating a prompt. The article I linked explains it all.

Comment: Exactly, but that goes against what's mentioned in the githubnext link!
Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: No it doesnt go against it. Read it again and compare it to the implemented vector db feature